# C++ regex difference between platforms

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::string s;
        s += '\x06';
        s += '\x00';

        std::regex r(std::string(1, '\x06') + '\x00');
        std::smatch sm;
        if (std::regex_search(s, sm, r))
        {
                std::cout << "Success\n";
                return 0;
        }

        std::cout << "Failure\n";
}
```

On Windows, I get "Success" while on Linux, I get "Failure". I use MSVC 19.28 on Windows and GNU 9.3.0 on Linux. Why is the output different?

Comment: I suspect zero characters interfere, what if you replace `\x00` with `\x01`? If helps, I would say it's either an MSVC bug or a C++ standard bug

Comment: Data point:  I get "Success" with **clang** (version 12.0.0).

Comment: You are right, it works with \x01.

Comment: @Eljay I still get the "Failure" with clang 10.0.0 (on Linux)

Comment: @user680891 its not clang, its libc++ vs libstdc++: https://godbolt.org/z/o4xcT6E67

Comment: It works in gcc if I replace '\x00' in the regex with "\\0". (i.e. the regex contains a backslash followed by a 0, not a byte with value zero).

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript, "*The decimal escape `\0` is NOT a backreference: it is a character escape that represents the nul character. It cannot be followed by a decimal digit.*", and [it works](https://ideone.com/8RFJXj).

Comment: Thank you for help. You just save me from major rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [C++ ECMAScript regex flavor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript),

> The decimal escape **`\0`** is NOT a backreference: it **is a character escape that represents the nul character**. It cannot be followed by a decimal digit.

So, to match a NULL char, you need to use `\0` *literal text*, a literal `\` char and a `0` char. You can define it with a regular string literal as `"\\0"` or - better - with a raw string literal, `R"(\0)"`.

The following [prints](https://ideone.com/8RFJXj) "Success":

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::string s;
        s += '\x06';
        s += '\x00';
        std::regex r(std::string(1, '\x06') + R"(\0)");
        std::smatch sm;
        if (std::regex_search(s, sm, r))
        {
                std::cout << "Success\n";
                return 0;
        }

        std::cout << "Failure\n";
}
```

Comment: Does the ECMAScript regex flavor explicitly *not* support a nul character directly in the regex? I don't see anything on that page that says that.

Comment: You can have a nul character in a `std::string`, and you can create a `std::regex` from a `std::string` like the OP does. So it follows that a `std::regex` object *can* contain a nul character. Whether it actually supports it or is supposed to support it is the question.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string: "4) Constructs the string with the first count characters of character string pointed to by s. **s can contain null characters**. The length of the string is count. The behavior is undefined if [s, s + count) is not a valid range."